# LocalStorage vs Redis on Front-end/NodeJS

Tags: angularjs, node.js, caching, redis

Would it make more sense to use localStorage to store common user information like username, image, etc... or would it make more sense to use Redis caching with NodeJs powering the front-end?

Answer (score 1):

If your process is only running in one machine, then there is no different of using local storage or redis. However, if you have multiple process running in different machines, then you have concern on how to update and synchronise the user information between the local storage of different machine.

Comment: Okay, that is useful. Since I am only looking to store the current information for as long as the user is logged in... the information is local and not distributed. However, you mentioned that in this case, it would make no difference. But I thought Redis would save the info at the Node.js end, whereas localStorage would be in the browser. So wouldn't it be much faster with localStorage? But safer with Redis?

Comment: Generally, the data stored in the server side(e.g. Redis, MySQL) is more secure than the local storage of the client machine because you will never know the security level of your users' machine. We usually do not store sensitive data (e.g. password, email, phone number, etc.) in the local storage of client machine because it's just insecure and potentially being used by hackers who can use those data to make fake identity to your service. That's why we only store Access Token in the client side under oAuth2 specification while storing the user information/permission in the auth server.

Comment: "store Access Token in the client side... while storing the user information/permission in the auth server", that doesn't sound right. Isn't the access token just as important.... or if not, more important?

Comment: That's not right, I think you don't really understand what is `Access Token`. For a good start, I think you can read the `RFC6749  doc for oAuth 2.0`, it tells you what is an access token, how to create it and how to safely handle it. `Access Token` (same concept as session key), has access duration and permission scope which allows you to make it transparent at the client side rather than the sensitive user information.

Comment: Hmm.. interesting. However, isn't it true that with this one access token I will  suddenly have access to a much wider range of data... even if just for a limited period?

Comment: `Access Token` should have lifetime and will be expired after certain time. It should also have permission scope which allow the `Access Token` limited to access certain amount of data, with the permission of your system or users.

Answer (score 0):

Use local storage for non sensitive information like user claims, to access it fast and without hitting service again.

> Local storage is more secure, and large amounts of data can be stored
>   locally, without affecting website performance. Unlike cookies, the
>   storage limit is far larger (at least 5MB) and information is never
>   transferred to the server. Local storage is per origin (per domain and
>   protocol). www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Redis caching require you to contact service to get the information.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, I am not sure what you are trying to say. You mentioned localStorage is not secure, and yet your quotation seems to say that it is more secure. Anyway, so which one would you recommend for user information? LocalStorage instead of Redis?

Comment: I would suggest to use local storage for basic user information.